# CSS: Best practice for selecting deeply nested elements

Tags: css

I frequently need to address generic elements inside some specific sections of a page. I find this approach most easy to understand in terms of what any rule is affecting:

```
.shop > .products > .product > .description > .warning {
   color: red;
 }
```

But I often see this:

```
.shopProductsProductDesc > .warning {
     color: red;
}
```

Does it really matter which approach is taken?

Comment: Shouldn't warning be a class selector in your post ? It's a tag selector for the moment

Comment: Both solutions can be valid, the first one is way more specific than the other: the second one will match any warning element which is a descendant of shopProductsProductDec while the first one needs a very specific dom configuration

Comment: If you are working outside a framework that would create scopes, the best practice, as I understand it, is to use specific classes without following a long path, even something like .shopProductsProductDescWarning{}, your stylesheet would be shorter and easier to read and understand

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

The selector `.shop > .products > .product > .description > .warning` to my understanding would be used for two cases:

1. You have multiple `warning` elements but you only want to select the elements inside your `description` and there are other selectors used for `warning` that you don't want to overwrite.
2. You need to overwrite a previous selector that is less specific. Ex. `.shop > .products > .product > .description .warning`

The other selector `.shopProductsProductDesc > .warning` is less specific than the first one but assuming the container of `.warning` has those two classes `.description.shopProductsProductDesc` then the outcome would be the same as the first one.

CSS is all about specificity, if your selector is more specific than the last one used the properties would change. This is why you have to be careful if you are using specific selectors because your last option to alter the properties would be to use `!important`.

I hope this helps to clear things out.

Answer (score 1):

After trying a few different styles, I think that personal preference (or a set standard if you have collaborators) is really the way to go. I prefer the second version, but the first one is also quite legible.

If you consider efficiency of what the browser has to do under the hood to render CSS styles, [BEM-style](https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/) for example, is usually the ultimate winner as it is the most lightweight for the browser. I use BEM for some layout/common elements.

In real life unless you are doing something seriously wrong, modern browsers and devices make this difference of CSS parsing and rendering somewhat negligible. But that is if you code everything well.

I've worked with spaghetti CSS codebases that could take minutes to render all SCSS  (it was a huge codebase, but a few files were big bottlenecks).

Answer (score 1):

According to my own experience, the second option is often best, not for direct technical reasons (in fine, it will perform the same), but rather for UX consistency and code maintenance.

The first option produce an "heavy" selector, which will be harder to override. It can be wanted, but it is often the sign of an overall messy CSS, because if everything is overconstraint, it is less easily reusable/extensible.

From my understanding of CSS and frontend reusable components, you would always only need two levels.

The style of your warning component (no size, no margin, size depends on where you will display it, and margin is position, only internal design here):

```
.warning {
   //Your design here
   font-size: 1.5rem;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: orange;
}
```

And the positionining and variants inside containers:

```
.container > .warning {
   //This is an example.
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   border: solid 1px red;
}
```

Having long CSS selectors will make things more complex, hard to follow for your teammates, and hard to override because you will probably need a longer CSS selector, and it never ends. Plus, you will get an heavier bundle at the end.

If you want an efficient UX, the UI shouldn't be that different everywhere, so you should not need to have that many variants of the same component. Otherwise, maybe you need multiple different components, but you certainly want a simple and efficient UX, and that often goes with not so much visual concepts, so you must avoid tons of variants.

Answer (score 1):

It matters because of specificity. The first style rule will always override the second, regardless of where they both appear in the stylesheet, because it is more specific (basically it has more class selectors in it).

That said, the first rule is a nightmare from a maintainability perspective, for a number of reasons:

1. It makes code incredibly hard to read and understand
2. It's harder to override (as we have seen).
3. If you change the structure of the HTML, it will break
4. You can only reuse it if you mirror the structure of the HTML exactly.

It's also bad from a performance perspective. When browsers are matching an element to a style rule they read each selector right-to-left and keep going till they either find a match or can exclude the rule. Therefore, the more simple the selector is, the faster a match can be determined. If a selector consists of just a single class name, the browser can match the element with the style rule more quickly than if it has to search upwards in the DOM tree.

The second rule is better, but optimal would be something like the following:

```
.shopProductsProductDesc--warning {
  color: red;
}
```

This solves all the problems above, and it's long enough that there's unlikely to be name clashes elsewhere, (though obviously not impossible).

In general, nesting selectors in CSS is bad practise, in my opinion, and the best CSS methodologies are those that have ways of avoiding this, e.g. BEM, CSS-in-JS.